# How to remove folder marked as library root in intellij?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea

How do i remove folder marked as library root in Intellij? Accidently marked as library root.

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? Check if you have [added it as a library](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/library.html#define-library) directory in Project Structure | Libraries or in Project Structure | Modules | Dependencies tabs and remove from there if so.

Answer (score 2):

You have an icon in the top right of your intelliJ window, right next to the maginifying glass and click on it. It's the icon that looks like a pile of papers in the screenshot I took below.

[image: Project Structure icon]

In the next window, click on **Modules** in the left sidebar and in the right part of the window, click on the name of your project.

In my case, it's the name of my Spring Artefact project.

[image: Project Structure window]

Now at the right, you have the context of your intelliJ project.

You can now select the folder you want to add or remove and click on the desired markup.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on the project, then File > Project Structure.
2. Go to the Dependencies tab, then find the entry that is adding such folder as a library root and remove that entry and click OK.